# Why is it moving the same circle every time I click, regardless of distance?

Tags: java, awt, mouselistener, mousemotionlistener

I am making a sports-play design simulator in which a "coach" adds a list of players, and you are able to move them around on screen using `mouseClicked`, `mouseDragged`, `mouseReleased`. It calculates the closest "player" via the distance formula in determining which circle to "move". However, regardless of the coordinates of my click, the first circle moved is the only circle moves, even if there is another circle closer. I was wondering if you all could help me out:

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
{
    xCoord = e.getX();
    yCoord = e.getY();
    //circleCenter = new Point((int)starterList.get(position).getPoint().getX(), (int)starterList.get(position).getPoint().getY());
    //circleCoords.add(circleCenter);
    //points = new ArrayList<Point>();
    for(i = 0; i < starterList.size(); i++)
    {
        closest = 3000;
        double difOfXes = starterList.get(position).getX() - xCoord;
        double difOfYes = starterList.get(position).getY() - yCoord;
        actualClosest = Math.sqrt(difOfXes * difOfXes + difOfYes * difOfYes);

        if(actualClosest < closest)
        {
            closest = actualClosest;
            position = i;
        }
    }
}

public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)    
{ 
    //Point circleClosest = circleCoords.get(position);

    starterList.get(position).setLocation(new Point(e.getX(), e.getY()));
    Point p = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
    starterList.get(position).setPoint(p);
    //starterList.get(position).getPoint().move((int) e.getX(), (int)e.getY());
    //set the coords of circleList at position= e.getx
    //points.add(p);
    //g.drawOval(p.getX(), p.getY(), 20,20);
    repaint();
}

public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
{
    Point release = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
    //int circleCenterLoc = circleCoords.indexOf(circleCenter);
    starterList.get(position).setPoint(release);
    //playersPoints.add(points);
    //playerIDs.add(position);
}
```

Comment: You have `closest = 3000` __inside__ your `for` loop. That means even if a circle in a previous iteration was closer, you still select the last circle if it's closer than 3000.

Comment: When I move it out of the for-loop it still does the same thing. I know what you mean though... regardless of where I click on the screen, it always moves the circle at position 0 in the arraylist. Where should I move the "closest = 3000" to? Or is there a better way to do this? Thanks so much for your help!!!

Comment: What happens if you move `closest = 3000;` up two lines, to immediately before the `for` statement?

Comment: Yeah, same thing is happening... always draws the first!

Comment: *"Yeah, same thing is happening..."* Tip: Add @DawoodibnKareem (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.